# Python Grouped bar chart with multiple x-labels

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I would like to plot a relatively simpler bar chart but struggling to plot using Matplotlib. Could I get some help please. I would like to prepare a chart as shown on this [Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvp5Z.png). A sample data is shown below for Tests 1, 2 and 3.

I have more than 20 tests results I would like to plot on a big single plot so I would prefer to cycle through color maps if possible.

My working code so far is this. As you can see [my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8i17h.png) is nowhere near what I need.

```
"""
        A     B     C
Test 1  1     1.5   2.5
Test 2  1.5   2     3.5
Test 3  1     0.5   1.5
"""

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

width = 0.2
x = np.arange(3)  

#Test 1
val1 = [1, 1.5, 1]
lab1_x = ['A' for i in range(len(val1))]
plt.bar(x, val1, width)
plt.xticks(x, lab1_x)

#Test 2
val2 = [1.5,2,3.5]
lab2_x = ['B' for i in range(len(val2))]
plt.bar(x+width, val2, width)
plt.xticks(x, lab2_x)

#Test 3
val3 = [1,0.5,1.5]
lab3_x = ['C' for i in range(len(val3))]
plt.bar(x+ 2*width, val3, width)
plt.xticks(x, lab3_x)


plt.legend(["Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"], loc = 'best')
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get what I needed. Sharing it here if anyone else is interested.

```
from random import seed
from random import random

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

# name of colour map 
cmap = mpl.cm.tab20c

totaltests = 10

# seed random number generator
seed(2)
A = []
# generate random numbers between 0-1
for _ in range(totaltests):
    A.append(2*random())
    
    
    
 # seed random number generator
seed(4)
B = []
# generate random numbers between 0-1
for _ in range(totaltests):
    B.append(2*random())
    
    
# sum of two columns    
sumbd = [x + y for x, y in zip(A, B)]



index = np.arange(len(sumbd))
bar_width = 0.3
shift = 0.5 # used to minimise gaps between each Test sets

ticklist = []
for i in ('A','B','C'):
    for _ in range(totaltests):
        ticklist.append(i)
    #print(A)
ticklist = tuple(ticklist)


plt.xticks(np.append(np.append(index-shift  , index-shift  + bar_width/1), index-shift  + 2*bar_width/1), # tick positions
           ticklist, # label corresponding to each tick
           rotation=0)

color_list = cmap([x for x in range(0,totaltests,1)])

Aplot = plt.bar(index-shift , A, bar_width-0.01, edgecolor ='black', color = color_list)
Bplot = plt.bar(index-shift  + bar_width/1, B, bar_width-0.01, edgecolor ='black', color = color_list)
sumbedplot = plt.bar(index-shift  +2* bar_width/1, sumbd, bar_width-0.01, edgecolor ='black', color = color_list)

handlesList = ['T'+str(x) for x in range(1,totaltests+1,1)]



# generate all handles for legend 
for i in range(0,totaltests,1):
    handlesList[i] = mpatches.Patch(color= color_list[i], label = "Test"+str(i+1))

# Rest of plotting 
plt.xlabel('X-axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-axis')
plt.title('Fig xxx')
plt.axis("tight")
plt.legend(handles=handlesList, bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.0), loc='upper left')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]